# On selecting first option of dropdown it should not dispaly in dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I select 1st option of dropdown it should not show in dropdown select.

```html
<select id="purchaseorderto" data-placeholder="items Name" name="purchaseorderto" class="form-control chosen-select" required="required">
     <option selected></option>
     <option value="addnewpoto" class="addnewtxt">Add new </option>
     <option value="1"> Abc</option>
     <option value="2"> Pqr </option>
     <option value="3"> xyz</option>
</select>
```

When I select Add new, it should not show in dropdown but it should open modal on selection of it.

Comment: i think adding selected disabled hidden is simple, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps

```js
$('#purchaseorderto').change(function(event) {

if($( "#purchaseorderto option:selected" ).val() == "addnewpoto")
{
$('#purchaseorderto').prop('selectedIndex',0);
  alert("do something");
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="purchaseorderto" data-placeholder="items Name" name="purchaseorderto" class="form-control chosen-select" required="required">
     <option selected></option>
     <option value="addnewpoto" class="addnewtxt">Add new </option>
     <option value="1"> Abc</option>
     <option value="2"> Pqr </option>
     <option value="3"> xyz</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Perfect, 
Thanks

Comment: There is 1 issue, its working perfect here but it wont work in my code, it shows Add new in my code & there is no error in console

Comment: did you wrap the jQuery code with $(document).ready(function() {})?

Comment: Yes i did, but its not working 

$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#purchaseorderto').change(function(event) {
                $modal = $('#poorderto');
                if ($("#purchaseorderto option:selected").val() == "addnewpoto") {
                    $('#purchaseorderto').prop('selectedIndex', 0);

                    $modal.modal('show');
                }
            });

        });

Comment: can you add link to your project?

Comment: Sorry dint get you

Comment: there are many reasons why it might not work, i need to see the page where you put the code and i can tell you why its not working. send a link to the page

Comment: Its on local machine, i am using jquery 3.1.1

Comment: when you have it on some server send a link

Comment: I am using chosen.jquery.js, when i tried it without chosen.jquery.js its working fine.

Comment: try to add $.noConflict()

Comment: How & where, pls let me know

$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#purchaseorderto').change(function(event) {
                $modal = $('#poorderto');
                if ($("#purchaseorderto option:selected").val() == "addnewpoto") {
                    $('#purchaseorderto').prop('selectedIndex', 0)

                    $modal.modal('show');
                }
            });
});

Comment: I try to use noConflict, but it shows an error, pls check error screen grab at
https://ibb.co/fnt4VQ

Comment: Still its showing error "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"

Here is my code
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.noConflict();
            $('#purchaseorderto').change(function(event) {
                $modal = $('#poorderto');
                if ($("#purchaseorderto option:selected").val() == "addnewpoto") {
                    $('#purchaseorderto').prop('selectedIndex', 0)

                    $modal.modal('show');
                }
            });
        });

Comment: try using jquery 2.1.1 and if its not working than i need to see the code

Answer (score 0):

Check this code snippet out. Is this what you're asking for?

```js
var prevVal;
$('#purchaseorderto').click(function() {
  prevVal = $(this).val();
}).change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === 'addnewpoto') {
    $(this).val(prevVal);
    alert('open model code here');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="purchaseorderto" data-placeholder="items Name" name="purchaseorderto" class="form-control chosen-select" required="required">
     <option value="addnewpoto" class="addnewtxt">Add new </option>
     <option value="1"> Abc</option>
     <option value="2"> Pqr </option>
     <option value="3"> xyz</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No no open modal on selection of Add new, but when i select Add new it should not dispaly in dropdown, it shoul be blank on selection of it

Comment: @JonPan Check now

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the `hidden`attribute in **HTML**.

```
<select>
<option selected disabled hidden>Add abc</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
<option value="4">Four</option>
<option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

```css
select{
 margin: 40px;
 width: 50%;   
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option selected disabled hidden>Add abc</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

Try with this example

Comment: i think adding `selected disabled hidden` is simple